# Make overflow scroll after certain breakpoint CSS

Tags: html, css

I have the following code where I have a (variable) number of buttons in a container, the buttons' position is adjusting correctly to the width of the container when resizing the screen, but what I want to achieve is at some breakpoint, the buttons should stop repositioning themselves and instead give the container an `overflow-y` scroll, and keep the buttons in their positions.

```css
.container {
  max-width: 800px;
  background-color: beige;
}

.btn {
  width: 80px;
}
.btn span{
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <button class="btn"><span>test</span></button>
  <button class="btn"><span>test123</span></button>
  <button class="btn"><span>test450354053</span></button>
  <button class="btn"><span>test23R02020202</span></button>
  <button class="btn"><span>test33030494</span></button>
  <button class="btn"><span>test403930390</span></button>
  <button class="btn"><span>test</span></button>
  <button class="btn"><span>test23423049</span></button>
  <button class="btn"><span>testé</span></button>
  <button class="btn"><span>test2340</span></button>
  <button class="btn"><span>test234234</span></button>
  <button class="btn"><span>test2342</span></button>
  <button class="btn"><span>test2342020</span></button>
  <button class="btn"><span>test2202349</span></button>
  <button class="btn"><span>testé</span></button>
  <button class="btn"><span>test234029</span></button>
  <button class="btn"><span>test20203030</span></button>
  <button class="btn"><span>test340</span></button>
  <button class="btn"><span>test234240</span></button>
  <button class="btn"><span>test2342340</span></button>
  <button class="btn"><span>test23420420</span></button>

</div>
```

Comment: You can use media queries to set breakpoints in css. Take a look at this https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this specific example a `min-width` with the given breakpoint (e.g. `400px`) and `overflow: auto` set on the `.container` will work fine

```css
.container {
  max-width: 800px;
  min-width: 400px;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: beige;
}

.btn {
  width: 80px;
}
.btn span{
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <button class="btn"><span>test</span></button>
  <button class="btn"><span>test123</span></button>
  <button class="btn"><span>test450354053</span></button>
  <button class="btn"><span>test23R02020202</span></button>
  <button class="btn"><span>test33030494</span></button>
  <button class="btn"><span>test403930390</span></button>
  <button class="btn"><span>test</span></button>
  <button class="btn"><span>test23423049</span></button>
  <button class="btn"><span>testé</span></button>
  <button class="btn"><span>test2340</span></button>
  <button class="btn"><span>test234234</span></button>
  <button class="btn"><span>test2342</span></button>
  <button class="btn"><span>test2342020</span></button>
  <button class="btn"><span>test2202349</span></button>
  <button class="btn"><span>testé</span></button>
  <button class="btn"><span>test234029</span></button>
  <button class="btn"><span>test20203030</span></button>
  <button class="btn"><span>test340</span></button>
  <button class="btn"><span>test234240</span></button>
  <button class="btn"><span>test2342340</span></button>
  <button class="btn"><span>test23420420</span></button>

</div>
```

Comment: thanks for helping, I cant produce the goal with your snippet. Say at 400px, the buttons should no longer reposition themselves, and instead we should have a horizontal scroll bar in the container to scroll the overflowing buttons.

Comment: this is exactly how this snippet work. the container is scrollable